# Recovering "lost" D2010 IDEs

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I had explorer crash on Windows 7 (Aero bells and whistles are enabled) and (afrer explorer restart) all of running IDE instances are no longer accessible via Windows UI except one single instance. Processes are still here, so i want my unsaved changes back. What should i do?

Do not suggest memory dumps, i'm leaving it as very latest resort because recovering source code from dump requires considerable manual work.

Already sent WM_ACTIVATE messages to all top-level windows which belongs to `bds.exe` - no success, except couple of "file changed, reload?" prompts.

---

Resolved by sending WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP to all process windows.

Delete this question or leave open for more ideas? (Honestly, i've encountered such problem only once, unsure if solution will be useful to anyone). But never ever use ShowWindow on all windows, BDS have tons of windows which supposed to be hidden.

---

Probable indirect cause: i was dragging files from Explorer via Aero Peek thumbnails onto Project Manager, one of operation ended with strange artifact in the form of file icon which permanently stuck on desktop where Project Manager was.

Comment: Don't you regularly save your source code edits (I do this about once every 2-3 minutes)?

Comment: @Misha, as side note: as aftermath for this incident i wrote an OTA wizard to perform timed auto-save. It appears to be what [ultra]frequent saves clutters revision history. (save every 2 min. gives 240 revision per working day)

Comment: @user759588: there is an option to autosave every time you compile / run (Tools menu > Options > Environment Options.)  That might be worth turning on?

Comment: "there is an option to autosave every time you compile/run" - I guess that guys that wrote the Delphi IDE code knew something about its stability so they added this handy feature :) :)

Comment: Just an idea: Did the Explorer automatically (re)started after crash? If no, try to press control+R to see the RUN box and type in explorer.exe

Comment: @Altar, "autosave on run" is very very old option, since TurboPascal days actually, when trying something from Peter Norton's book might make you to press Reset after running your program :) Explorer restarted ofc, IDEs' windows appeared to be hidden. See "probable indirect cause". Note: that might or might not be related, i'm not sure, just other glitch happened nearby.

Comment: I think I tend to forget about that function as my left hand learned to perform that function automatically :) Every 2 minutes it presses Control+Shit+S :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you think that the IDE is still running and responsive?

Could you send the keystroke Ctrl-Shift-S to Delphi from another app to execute a File, Save All command?

Tom

Comment: Running - yes. Responsible - nothing happened to IDEs, so should be, but i have to check to be sure. About keystroke - which windows i should send to (there are lot)?

Comment: All 380(!) windows belonging to `bds.exe` responded, so all instance are alive and healthy.

Comment: This way worked, no idea which window processed Ctrl+Shift+S, but save dialogs were invoked. I wish i did that from beginning, because experimenting with various functions and messages crashed two of instances.

Comment: Ctrl-Shft-S is engrained in my motor neurons. I even inadvertently use it in other apps regularly as well and am often surprised at what happens...

Comment: I started on a ZX81 in the early 80's and the machine frequently "tanked", so ever since then I save often, very often, and this is a habit that has never left me...

Comment: First two things I did after installing the IDE was to make sure **Editor Options - Create Backup Files** and **Autosave options - Editor files** are checked. Version control is great for stopping points but committing after every minor change isn't practical. That's where these features come in handy. They've saved my skin more times than I can count.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Task Manager. If explorer is truly down you can get to Task Manager using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, if you still have a Taskbar you can right-click on the taskbar and select "Start Task Manager". You'll see all your applications in the applications pane. Select the one you want and then press "Switch To". Or right-click on your application and select "Switch to".

Comment: Why downvote without a comment? What I'm describing here works very well if you no longer have a Taskbar or the Taskbar no longer shows your applications.

Comment: +1, while this may or may not work for the OP (explorer crashes can do strange things sometimes) it is a possible answer.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, "no longer accessible via Windows UI". It was the key point of the question.

Comment: As a sidenote, just hit CTRL+SHIFT+ESC for the Task Manager if your explorer is still kinda up and running. During win32/com/thread programming I often manage to leave the taskbar non-responsive, but this still works.

Comment: @user, an other equally big part of your question was `"I had explorer crash on Windows 7"`, my solution works with explorer crashed. `"IDE instances are no longer accessible via Windows UI"` is ambiguous, because you were using a Windows UI after all - or did you issue your WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages from a Linux laptop? You should have taken the opportunity to explain this with a comment, downvote included if that's "your style", but the downvote without a comment is useless.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, you should read entire question instead of replying to the part you know the answer for. This usually leads to non-useful answers, and this case is not an exception, hence the downvote. Seriously, did you really think i know about processes yet clueless about invoking Task Manager?

Comment: @user, mind telling me what constitutes a "Windows UI" for you? Don't pick on me because *you* didn't make your question 100% clear. Some days my crystal-ball works better then others. And seriously, how should I know *you know* Task Manager can be invoked using CTRL+ALT+DEL even if Explorer is completely dead, and you can use it to switch to an application that's other ways inaccessible? Did you write that in the question?

Comment: @user, And just to make it clear, I don't have a problem with the downvote, especially since it's your question and you're the one judging what works and what doesn't. What I do have a problem with is down voting without a comment, because you don't give me the chance to reply (or fix the answer), and you don't give other users any insight into why you think the answer is wrong. In my opinion that's a useless vote, as useless as they get.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, did *you* add a comment requesting clarification? No, you chose to interpret random part of the problem and gave answer to  resulting rendition. No surprise such reply was useless. *Of course its all my fault, heh. Really.*

Comment: @user, no need to ask for clarifications, I was certain this is your problem, and still am. The only "hint" that you're actually not a n00b user dealing with a simple problem is your request to avid "memory dumps". To me that had the contrary effect: who would even considering trying to recover source code from a memory dump? And who would be caught with *multiple* IDE instances containing *unsaved* source code?

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, yes, this conversation is excellent example of contrary effect and lots of free time. You can keep insisting on what task manager can show invisible windows on application tab if you want, i have absolutely no objections. BTW, multiple instances remark reveals few experience with D2010.